# C++: Structural design pattern for creating aggregate class whose constituents express what they want exposed

Tags: c++, c++20

I'm trying to come up with a structural design for the following usecase, but I'm comming up short.
The only way I've been able to do it is by explicitly creating new methods in `Agg` that expose
the feature classes methods.

I have a class that I use as an agregator for other 'feature' classes.

```
struct Agg {
    
    void MyMethod() {
        return 42;
    }
    
    void F1OperationA() {
        mF1.OperationA();
    }
    
    void F2OperationB() {
        mF2.OperationB();
    }
    
private:
    Feature1 mF1;
    Feature2 mF2;
    // ...
    FeatureN mFN;
};
```

This `Agg` class has its own set of operations. It also exposes ***some*** of the feature classes API surface. My wish is to automate that, in some way, such that the feature classes express their API surface which they want available outside of the `Agg` class, and for such methods to be accessed as if they were part of the `Agg` class. That is, the feature classes, themselves, express what is accessible outside of Agg.

I've been trying to craft some template magic to accomplish this but, so far, no luck. I'm thinking of something like this:

```
Agg agg;
agg->OperationA(); // Really calls mFeature1.OperationA()
```

If this is not possibly, then my fallback will be to make methods in Agg class which return some type of sliced version of the feature
classes, such that the return objects only exposed the feature class' external api surface.

```
// Feature1Proxy only provides a subset of the Feature1 class.
Feature1Proxy Agg::GetFeature1() { return Feature1Proxy(mFeature1); }
```

In this latter case, can such a Proxy wrapper be made generic, such that I don't
have to create one for each feature?

Comment: If it's really that tedious to compose, then use multiple inheritance instead of composition? What you want exposed should be marked public, and what you don't should either be marked protected or private.

Comment: Looks like this is trying to reinvent public/private inheritance.

Comment: Subclassing is not a good answer, here, because the Feature class fields would be duplicated in the Agg class. That's undesired.